# Using XLSX package in Node to upload n read Excel file with custom object keys

Tags: node.js, xlsx

Need to upload an Excel file to store data in a Node/Mogo application.
I am able to upload the file and extract the data.
The data is in the form of an Array of Objects with each Object having keys as the column titles of the excel file.
I need to use my own Object Keys to replace the keys generated from column titles.
This is to map the properties of a Model in which this data is getting saved.
How do I achieve this, assuming the order of the columns is known to me.

**Node Controller:**

```
    const currDirName = __dirname;
    const basePath = currDirName.slice(0, currDirName.length - 11); // removing controllers from path
    const filePath = basePath + 'assets/uploadedFiles/' + req.savedFileName
    const file = xlsx.readFile(filePath);
    let fileData = [];
    const temp = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[0]])
    temp.forEach(res => fileData.push(res))
  
    console.log('uploaded file data: ', fileData);
```

**console output**

```
[{
    'Sr.\r\nNo.': 1,
    'Name and address': 'Shop No. 3, ABC Arcade,\r\n' +     
      'Opp. PKA, XYZ Lane,\r\n' +
      'J.P. Road, Andheri (West), Mumbai - 400068. Maharashtra',
    PAN: 'AAAPA1234B',
    'Authorised Person (AP) code': 'MCX/AP/6337',
    'Date of Approval': 40570,
    'Date of withdrawal of approval': 41508,
    'Name of the Member through which AP was registered': 'ABC Commodity Services Pvt. Ltd.',        
    'Name of Directors / Shareholders': 'N.A.'
},....
]
```

Need to have my own keys for the above objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading the sheet, you can add your custom headers by providing [`headers` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#json) which contains array of strings which will be used as headers, i.e. object properties.

Also, use `.slice(1)` to skip the first row with headers.

To get date value, add `cellDates: true` flag to `.readFile` options (you'll get a date istead of a number in your example `'Date of Approval': 40570`, as per docs: [Dates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#dates)).

Try this:

```
const currDirName = __dirname;
const basePath = currDirName.slice(0, currDirName.length - 11); // removing controllers from path
const filePath = basePath + 'assets/uploadedFiles/' + req.savedFileName

// pass options to parse date
const file = xlsx.readFile(filePath, { cellDates: true });

// add your headers array here
const opts = {
    header: ['header1', 'header2..etc']    
};

const file = xlsx.readFile(filePath);
// slice to skip headers row
let fileData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[0]], opts).slice(1);

console.log('uploaded file data: ', fileData);
```

Comment: The column headers part is working fine.  But the dates columns are still showing numbers.  I have added ```cellDates: true``` in options. Is there any other setting?

Comment: right, it goes with `readFile` actually.. try the updated code

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Comment: An update. Just to test something when I used slice(1) without opts,  ```xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[0]]).slice(1);``` the row 2 onwards gets sliced. i.e. data is parsed from 3rd row onwards. It looks like while parsing data the header row is skipped. Therefore, I had to remove slice(1) from the code. Hope my understanding is correct and there is no other setting to this.

Comment: sure, you can omit that and adapt to your input file and data, but, no, nothing is skipped with these options. Not sure why, it probably depends on your input file.. Try testing some dummy file with a few rows, it should work without skipping anything, and if the first row contains headers, then without `slice` it should end in the results as well..

Comment: check if you have some merged cells/rows, it might be that

Comment: Header row is getting skipped while parsing the data for sure. I tried with two different dummy files having different column structures. By the way,  I also need to read the header row, i.e. the column titles and match it with the data structure I have on the server, to ensure the correctness of the file being uploaded. With the current way of working I am not able to read the first row.  So I am using a workaround by having two title rows. Is there any other way I can read the first row to check the column titles of the file being uploaded.

Comment: can't reproduce, works as expected for me.. the docs say it's not skipping anything: _`By default, sheet_to_json scans the first row and uses the values as headers`_

Comment: That's correct. I think I miscommunicated. The first row is read, but it is used for creating keys of the Objects. Now if any of the cell value in the second row is blank, then for the first object element of the array, i.e. fileData[0], that particular header(key) will not exist. I need to use fileData[0] to validate each and every column title for the correctness of the file format, and hence I am using this workaround of having two title rows.

Comment: ah, right, you're missing object property. it's default behavior, add `defval: ''` to `opts`, it will then insert the value you provide for that header/object property when the cell is blank: _`If defval is not specified, null and undefined values are skipped normally. If specified, all null and undefined points will be filled with defval`_